# Ranking structure with Java and MySQL Server Side

Tags: java, mysql, caching, nosql, ranking

I am developing the server side of a game. I am using Play Framework and MySQL. The API consumers are going to be mobile devices.

The rank is a SQL view based on some user's values. So I don't have a table called Rank, I always use a SQL view to create the Rank. These values are always changing depending on user's actions.

There is a problem in this, because let's suppose a user is on his mobile phone and it is looking at the rank. As it is paginated and I am using views, there can be some sync problems between the pages. Example: I am the first one in Ranking (Page 0). So I scroll down, a req to get page 1 is made. In this meantime a lot of events happened with all players, so I could be in the second page and in the first page because the app on the mobile phone can't know this change.

Every three minutes a job is executed, so I thought to always let this view cached and update it when this job runs. So users will always see the same ranking.

I though about using Memcached or Redis, so every time I could save the ranking view in Cache, but it appears they are not going to work as I need (I tested Memcached).

Does anybody have an idea how to cache this view? Does anybody have a better idea?

I am thinking about using a NoSQL database to store this, but I don't know if it makes sense.

The rank update operation must be fast.

Thank you all!

Comment: I think you should read about comet, WebSocket or Akka steam. At this point, I think comet will solve your problem.

Comment: I had some experience with WebSockets, but I did not get how a socket could help on this situation.